# How to connect Macbook to Windows in the wireless mode?

Tags: macbook-pro, network, windows

I have a Windows and MacBook. I use Windows for my Visual Studio - Xamarin App programming. I connect Macbook to the Windows using USB Port. Both are shared. When i run the project in Windows, I can view the iPhone Simulator on my Macbook.

Now, i am in the process of considering "Go to my PC" Citrix online which i connect my Windows from  Macbook.

My question is, without using USB cable to connect windows, is there a way to connect wireless.

i.e. From any network, Connect the Windows through Go to my pc and run the project. Upon running the project the iPhone Simulator should show up in the Macbook.

Answer (score 1):

GotToMyPC is much like LogMeIn, Teamviewer and other similar apps, they require communication back to the company's servers so they can contact the app installed on the other computer. Don't get me wrong they are great and helpful utilities but if all you are trying to do is screen share between Mac and PC (without a third party in the middle) there is a way.

The Mac does not use Microsoft's RDP protocol, rather it uses VNC. Yes Apple Remote Desktop is based on VNC. If you turn on screen sharing on your Mac and get a VNC program for your PC you should be able to connect to the Mac from your PC as long as both are on the same network.

Comment: this sounds very helpful. I wasn't aware of VNC Program. I will test it by today... thanks

Comment: steps provided will help me to connect mac from windows. How do i connect windows from Mac ?

Comment: Use Microsoft Remote Desktop